# model binder not getting used for ajax requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-binding

I have a custom model binder for decimals that contain a comma which is based on this
article about [Model Binding Decimal Values](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx)

This works fine except when used by an ajax request

It works fine for ajax requests that do not contain an amount with a comma (i.e. values less than a thousand)

the error is

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'amount' 
 of non-nullable type 'System.Decimal' for method 
'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult IsDepositRequired(System.String, System.String, System.String, 
  Boolean, System.Decimal, System.DateTime)' in 'Client.Controllers.DealingController'. An 
  optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an 
  optional parameter.
  Parameter name: parameters
  at System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.
    ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo)
```

The model binder is correctly registered in the golbal.asax

any idea what I could have missed
thanks

ajax code:

```
$.post('/Dealing/IsDepositRequired', {
                baseCurrency: deal.baseCurrency,
                termsCurrency: deal.termsCurrency,
                dealtCurrency: deal.dealtCurrency,
                isBuy: deal.direction == 'BUY',
                amount: deal.dealtCurrency == deal.baseCurrency ? deal.baseAmount : deal.termsAmount,
                valueDate: deal.valueDate
            }, function (show) {
                if (show) {
                    $('.Deposit').fadeIn(500);
                } else {
                    $('.Deposit').hide();
                }
            }, 'json');
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult IsDepositRequired(string baseCurrency, string termsCurrency, string dealtCurrency, bool isBuy, decimal amount, DateTime valueDate)
{
```

Firebug Net Console :

```
amount          100,000.00
baseCurrency    GBP
dealtCurrency   GBP
isBuy           true
termsCurrency   EUR
valueDate           30/10/2012
```

Source:

`baseCurrency=GBP&termsCurrency=EUR&dealtCurrency=GBP&isBuy=true&amount=100%2C000.00&valueDate=30%2F10%2F2012`

Comment: The model binder will be used - you are probably not creating your AJAX request correctly.  Have you tried using Fiddler or something like that to see the actual request?

Comment: Ive added the ajax code above

Comment: and also what I see in the Firebug console

Comment: Can you include your controller?

Comment: Does an ajax request work when you disable the the custom model binder?

Comment: What is the deal object? Are you getting this data from model properties or items in the View? Post your view :)

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call to the action is probably not sending amount with the correct querystring param or form encoded value. You can check the request with fiddler to see what it getting sent.

Comment: yeah, had forgot to explicitly specify that I was sending json

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your action method take that many parameters, you're best off putting them into your existing model/new model and wrapping the view fields in a form, then serializing the form into the request. Something like this?

Assuming this is the model with your fields in:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string BaseCurrency { get; set; }
    public string TermsCurrency { get; set; }
    public string DealtCurrency { get; set; }
    public bool IsBuy { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValueDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then assuming you have a view something like:

```
@model MyModel

//putting these fields in a form with an id of myForm
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BaseCurrency)
//rest of your fields...
```

Then in your ajax call when specifying the data you just send the following as your data:

```
$("#myForm").serialize()
```

Then have your action method take the model, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult IsDepositRequired(MyModel model)
```